# Excel VBA - Loop to insert formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I've come across a worksheet full of formulas mistakes. The project itself its very repetitive so I decided to write some simple VBA code in order to save me some time.

The problem is the my code did not work. I thought indeed it was a simple problem but it has been a pain in my neck.

I've cut out all those repetting pieces of the code to make it easier to understand.

```
Sub corrigirerro()
    Dim r, i As Integer

    For r = 17 To 28
        i = r - 16    
        Worksheets(r).Select    
        Range("D73").ClearContents    
        Range("D73").Formula = "=SEERRO(SOMARPRODUTO('RD - " & i & "'!D266:D268;'RD - " & i & "'!E266:E268)/SOMA('RD - " & i & "'!D266:D268);0)"
```

Comment: What the specific issue you are having? Do you get an error? Is the output not that you expect?

Comment: What didn't work and what was the expected result?

Comment: You may need to convert i to a string value first otherwise the & will not work properly.

Comment: @Tom the `&` operator brutally converts anything to `String` which is convertible. No explicit conversion is needed.

Comment: I tend not to expect implicit conversions to work. Even it will in this case, I would advise against it.

Comment: @Tom it all depends on the language you are using.  It is fine to do this in VBA.

Comment: I just tried this (converted to English formulas): `=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Sheet2!D266:D268,Sheet2!E266:E268)/SUM(Sheet2!D266:D268),0)` with `1, 2, 3` in `D266:268` and `4, 5, 6` in `E266:268` and I got `5.333333`.  It works even if I put it in a macro: `Range("A8").Formula = "=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Sheet" & i & "!D266:D268,Sheet" & i & "!E266:E268)/SUM(Sheet" & i & "!D266:D268),0)"` Are you sure the sheets are correctly named?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is using the semi-colon that your system has set for the list separator in the regional settings. VBA sets the [Range .Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) with a comma regardless of the regional settings but does have a [Range .FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) that will use the regional settings.

```
    Range("D73").Formula = "=SEERRO(SOMARPRODUTO('RD - " & i & "'!D266:D268, 'RD - " & i & "'!E266:E268)/SOMA('RD - " & i & "'!D266:D268), 0)"
    Range("D73").FormulaLocal = "=SEERRO(SOMARPRODUTO('RD - " & i & "'!D266:D268; 'RD - " & i & "'!E266:E268)/SOMA('RD - " & i & "'!D266:D268); 0)"
```

Switch your formula to commas or use the `.FormulaLocal` property.

Comment: Doesn't .Formula also require international names for functions?

Comment: I don't have the time to switch a machine over to PT-BR Office (and regional settings to `;`) right now but I believe that `SEERRO` does not have to be changed to `IFERROR` for `.Formula` to work; only the `;` to a `,`.                Hopefully we  will get a response from the OP on this. (My gmail is *still* screwed up from changing a machine over to IT-IT to assist a European user last year!)